# Why do I have two different python envs linked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm using pyenv with python version 3.9.1

I have two projects. I created virtualenv for each of them with "python -m venv env".

When I install tox in one env, I can use it in the other.

When I uninstall tox in one env, I lose it in the other.

This is not the behavior I'm expecting at least.

Comment: I'm not a python expert. Now I realized that if I separate pip execution enviroments using python -m pip install tox, then I have the behavior I expected.

Comment: Have you deactivate successfully and activate the other one? Are you sure you install for both?